# Access modem GUI

Tags: modem, gui

I have gone through all the materials here but am still having some problems, as in it doesn't work.

I have a century link modem in bridge mode (192.168.0.1), and linksys 1900ac with stock software (192.168.1.1) and am also trying to use a linksys older router 54gts with WRT software.

I had issues putting wrt on the 1900ac so left it stock.  Changed the second router to 192.168.1.2.  I can access both routers fine.  I put in the required startup and firewall scripts into the 54gts router (this worked fine when it was my sole router).

What am I doing wrong that I still can't access my bridged modem?  Any ideas?

I have 2 nics on my pc at my disposal too if that matters but am only using one at this time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using a second nic directly into the modem.  I only activate that network when I need to access the modem gui.